# Creating a python dictionary more cleanly

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to create a dictionary of dictionaries involving timedeltas, which should be converted into days (rounded off to 1 d.p.).

The inputs are an `OrderedDict` and a values_list. The initialised `OrderedDict` and the values_list look like this:

```
OrderedDict(
    [('Jul 2015', defaultdict(<function __main__.<lambda>>, {})),
     ('Aug 2015', defaultdict(<function __main__.<lambda>>, {})),
     ('Sep 2015', defaultdict(<function __main__.<lambda>>, {})),
     ('Oct 2015', defaultdict(<function __main__.<lambda>>, {})),
     ('Nov 2015', defaultdict(<function __main__.<lambda>>, {})),
     ('Dec 2015', defaultdict(<function __main__.<lambda>>, {}))]
)

values_list = [
    (
        datetime.date(2015, 7, 1),
        datetime.timedelta(1, 11111),
        datetime.timedelta(2, 22222),
        datetime.timedelta(3, 33333)
    ),
    (
        datetime.date(2015, 8, 1),
        datetime.timedelta(4, 44444),
        datetime.timedelta(5, 55555),
        None
    ),
    ...
]
```

and the output should look like this:

```
output_matrix = {
    'Jul 2015': {
        'time_1': 0.1,
        'time_2': 0.3,
        'time_3': 0.4
    }
    'Aug 2015': {
        'time_1': 0.5,
        'time_2': 0.6,
        'time_3': 0
    }
    ...
}
```

Note that `None` timedeltas are converted into `0`.
This seems easy to do, but the solution I've got so far is really ugly, and I'm sure there's a better way of doing it.

My ugly solution:

```
matrix = OrderedDict()
today = timezone.now()
tzinfo = timezone.get_current_timezone()
headers = ['Time 1', 'Time 2', 'Time 3']  # Used elsewhere, could possibly use here?

# Initialise OrderedDict
for i in range(5, -1, -1):
    d = datetime(today.year, today.month, 1, tzinfo=tzinfo) - relativedelta(months=i)
    matrix[d.strftime("%b %Y")] = defaultdict(lambda: 0)

matrix = build_matrix(matrix, values_list)

def build_matrix(matrix, values_list)
    ''' Populates a matrix and converts timedeltas into days. '''
    for month, time1, time2, time3 in values_list:
        month_label = month.strftime("%b %Y")
        if time1 is not None:
            matrix[month_label]['Time 1'] = round(time1.seconds/60/60/24, 1)
        if time2 is not None:
            matrix[month_label]['Time 2'] = round(time2.seconds/60/60/24, 1)
        if time3 is not None:
            matrix[month_label]['Time 3'] = round(time3.seconds/60/60/24, 1)

    return matrix
```

How can I improve on this solution?

Comment: Without changing the fairly awkward output data structure, I don't see much that can be improved. Perhaps this question would be better at [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)?

Comment: Why do you have nested dictionaries? I hope it's not because of performance reasons

Comment: @Untitled123 I nested them so that it would look neater; every month has its own data, and then I want all the months' data in another dict. Is there something wrong with this? I'm actually using this data to feed into Google's visualisation charts to chart out each month's data.

Comment: When you plot out data, datetime objects/timestamps can easily be binned into months or the like. Manually doing it at this step is needlessly confusing (generally speaking) imo.

Comment: You're getting into database territory with the complexity of your data state. You might be better off initializing a simple SQLite database with SQLAlchemy and performing whatever calculations you need using that API.